# How justify text in custom curriculum template

Tags: templates, text, justification

I download from the Overleaf store the following template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv (customised-curve).

I modified the first section of the template: "Employment History", in "About Me", and I would like to justify the text inside this section.

In particular, the section that I would justify is structured as follow:

```
\begin{rubric}{About Me}
 Some long text
\end{rubric}
```

And this is the file settings.sty associate:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 23 Oct, 2022
%

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   
\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\iffieldformatundef{labelnumberwidth}{%
  % if author-year style
  \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}%
}{%
  % if numeric style
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}}}%
  \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}%
  \AtEveryBibitem{\stepcounter{bibitem}}%
}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{doi}{}{\clearfield{url}}}

% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.5em}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpretofieldformat{doi}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}
\xpretofieldformat{url}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white,left, color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{l}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\mynames}[1]{\def\my@namelist{#1}}
\newtoggle{boldname}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{boldname}%
  \foreach \my@fname / \my@gname in \my@namelist {%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\my@fname}}
                 and
                 test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\my@gname}}}
      {\global\toggletrue{boldname}}{}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{boldname}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{boldname}%
  \foreach \my@fname / \my@gname in \my@namelist{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\my@fname}}
                 and
                 test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\my@gname}}}
      {\global\toggletrue{boldname}\breakforeach}{}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{boldname}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
}


\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{settings} % last <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

I tried different solutions but without success. In particular, I also modified the line "\keyalignment{r}" to "\keyalignment{l}", but the only effect of this modification is the change of the alignment from right to left.

How can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/curve) on page 9 in section *Plain text entries* states:

> \text {<contents>}
>
> Sometimes, you may feel the need to insert plain text in the middle of a rubric, without the fancy key/prefix formatting stuff. As of version 1.16, CurVe provides a \text macro for that. Plain text occupies the whole page width. If you whish to further distinguish it from the surrounding entries, you can use \par to add vertical space before and/or after the text.

It seems you should enclose standalone texts in `\text{...}`, that is

```latex
\begin{rubric}{About Me}
\text{About you ...}
\end{rubric}
```

This should have the effect you expect.

As a side note, the way this class works is you create an extra file e.g. `aboutme.tex` which should contain the code above. Then add the line

```
\makerubric{aboutme}
```

in the main file.